# Jest test for method call inside componentWillMount fails

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

In my component, I am calling `this.props.foo()` inside `componentWillMount`:

```
public componentWillMount() {
    this.props.foo();
}
```

Now I want to test that this method is called, with jest:

```
it("should call startCountdown when mounted.", () => {
        const foo= jest.fn();
        const newProps: ComponentProps = {
            foo,
            ...defaultProps,
        };
        renderComponent(newProps);
        expect(foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

`renderComponent` does this:

```
const renderComponent= (props: ComponentProps = defaultProps) => {
        const rendered = TestRenderer.create(
            <Component {...props}/>);
        return rendered.root;
    };
```

How come this test fails? What is the correct way to spy on `componentWillMount` in React Native?

Comment: what is `defaultProps`, does it include `foo`?

Comment: @HermanStarikov yes, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        const newProps: ComponentProps = {
            ...defaultProps,
            foo,
        };
```

`foo` should come last to override other props

Comment: In my defense, it's all linter's fault, wanting object properties to be ordered alphabetically :). Thank you!

Comment: Haha, linter really should not be doing that.